# Magento 1.9 custom modules not working after site cloned

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have just duplicated my Magento website to create a development website, everything looks to be working on it apart from the custom modules. Does anyone know why they would not be working?

Thanks

Comment: make sure same php version enabled on development server

Comment: @GohilRajesh Thanks for the suggestion but they are already on the same version.

Comment: What error is displayed?

Comment: I should mention that I can see the modules in Configuration -> Advanced and they are enabled.

Comment: I can't see any errors the modules just aren't showing in the admin area.